# Discrepency between p value and confidence interval in glm

Tags: generalized-linear-model

Consider estimating the binomial success parameter using `glm`.

```
glm(cbind(3,10)~1, family = binomial()) # 3 successes, 10 failures
```

The table is

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)  -1.2040     0.6583  -1.829   0.0674 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance:  0.0000e+00  on 0  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: -3.2646e-24  on 0  degrees of freedom
AIC: 4.7333

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 3
```

Note that the model fails to reject the null at the 5% significance level.  However, if I then estimate the confidence interval for this model I get

```
     2.5 %     97.5 % 
0.06302025 0.49511505
```

Note now that the null value is outside the confidence interval, and we should reject the null hypothesis.  Some documentation reading reveals there is another method called `confint.default` based on asymptotic normality which returns the following confidence interval

```
                2.5 %    97.5 %
(Intercept) 0.07626731 0.5215448
```

Does R use asymptotic normality in the glm coefficient table but profile likelihood when I call `confint`?  What else may explain this discrepancy?

Comment: The point estimate doesn't fall within either confidence interval - have you described what you've done correctly?

Comment: Oh, I see, the CI's are for odds, not log odds.